# How to download ASIHTTPRequest folder for iOS 8

Tags: objective-c-blocks

[image] 1. how to download ASIHTTPRequest folder in iOS 8. I am using previous downloaded folder in my project but showing some warning. i just want to remove those warning.

Comment: Can you also add the warning? Hard to say otherwise.

Comment: YES, I uploaded one image, in that image all warning are showing. Thanks